# Deleting a scaffold, can i do it?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I stupidly added a field to my database, ran a `scaffold` later on but now have this field all through my aspNetUser files. Whats the process to escape my mistake here? I deleted the field from the database but now I have issues on load relating to an SQL error.

Comment: Regenerate your scaffold? This is how database-first works in EF Core. You alter your database, then rescaffold. As such, that means you should never be making any manual changes to your entities, as that will all get wiped the next time you scaffold.

Comment: thanks for your help, in the heat of a project i have deleted and broke projects before. So i basically deleted the column in the SQL Management then ran a scaffold on VS.